# jQuery - reference a selector that is included with .load

Tags: php, jquery

can you help me with this?

I have a local website that displays "news". The newest one is displayed when the page is first loaded, but the older news are loaded only if the visitor clicks a link called #oldnews:

```
$('#oldnews').load('ajax/older_news.php');
```

The "older_news.php" file, after is loaded, has another link which is meant to hide these older news. However, this link is not working.

The jQuery code that handles this "hide" mechanism is in the homepage, so my guess is that jQuery doesn't hide the news because it doesn't know that the link exists (since it is only loaded when the user clicks the link).

Any insights on the better approach to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: You need event delegation to handle dynamically added content, `$(document).on('click', '#idOfLink', function() { //do stuff });`

Comment: You are correct in your assumption that the binding doesn't happen because the element doesn't exist at the time that the original jQuery code runs. If you post the relevant link markup that comes from older_news.php, we can help you write an `on()` statement that binds the even to the element when it is added to the DOM.

Comment: Here's the [API reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Just FYI, if you're using an older version of jQuery (pre-1.7), you'll need to use `.live()` or `.bind()` instead.

Comment: @EmmyS `.live()` or `.delegate()`

Comment: @KevinB - I missed delegate, but according to the API, all three are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things. As pointedd out in comments, you can use `.delegate`. In the new versions of jQuery (1.7+) this is extremely simple.

```
$(function() {  //  good old $(document).load(function(){ //shorter!
    //  use document to asign delegation
    //      asign an event like "click" or "keyup"
    //          asign a selector like "#elementID" or ".element-class-name" or even just "ul li"
    $(document).on("event", "selector", function(e) {
        /*  DO WORK
                like any other event callback
        */
    })

    // for older versions of jQuery, use .delegate or .bind
    $(document).delegate("event", "selector", function(e) {  })
})
```

However, don't forget, `.load` has a callback function as well. Thus you could do something like:

```
$(function() {
    $('#oldnews').load('ajax/older_news.php', function(response, status, jqXHR) {
        $(".new-stuff:visible").hide();
    });
})
```

- [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/#entry-longdesc)
- [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/#entry-longdesc)
- [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function)
- [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Thank you all, I will see if I understand what to do based on all your feedback. The website is this one: http://www.scopiomagazine.com/  (has several sections, and most of them have an "older" switch that works, that loads the external file, which has, in turn, the "hide" switch that does not work)